# Using Xalan in Eclipse plugin

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, xalan

I am facing problems with using xalan in eclipse plugin.
When I try to create factory instance by:

```
TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance("org.apache.xalan.processor.TransformerFactoryImpl", null);
```

I get error:

```
javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactoryConfigurationError: Provider org.apache.xalan.processor.TransformerFactoryImpl not found
...
```

I have following libs in plugin classpath: xml-apis.jar, xercesImpl.jar, serializer.jar, xalan.jar

I even can't create class instance by:

```
c = Class.forName("org.apache.xalan.processor.TransformerFactoryImpl");
Object o = c.newInstance();
```

It returns ClassNotFoundException

But I can create instances of other classes from same jar and can run same code outside eclipse without problem.

Any idea?

**Edit:** TransformerFactory instantiating class (say "class1") is part of an external library added in the plugin classpath wheras the xalan.jar is also in plugin classpath. If I move this "class1" into plugin, it finds the provider and works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though I have seen this problem once, but I am not very sure how i solved it.

If you are using JDK 1.5 or above then try removing `xml-apis.jar`. It was needed for Java 1.4 to support XML.

**Update 1**

---

Ok. From your question I inferred that you are writing a eclipse plug-in. If yes, then have you added the above jars using `plugin.xml->Runtime->classpath`? If not try to do so. Eclipse plugin considers only its runtime->classpath entries

**Update 2**

---

To me it still appears as a classpath resolution issue. Though, its hard to say why its happening. For a try you can also check by changing the order of included jars in `plugin.xml->Runtime->classpath`.

Hope this will help.

**PS:** Since you are working on eclipse plug-in development therefore I would suggest you to go through this article [Eclipse - a tale of two VMs and many classloaders](http://www.eclipsezone.com/articles/eclipse-vms/).

Comment: Thank you @Favonius for your answer. Got your point and removed said jar but unfortunately, it didn't work. Also tried xalan, excrces and serializer plugins instead of plain libs. Didn't help either. Any other idea?

Comment: @Leslie Norman: Ok. From your question I inferred that you are writing a eclipse plug-in. If yes, then have you added the above jars using `plugin.xml->Runtime->classpath`? If not try to do so. Eclipse plugin considers only its `runtime->classpath` entries.

Comment: I have new findings that I added at the bottom of the question. Please have a look. I apologies if it is changing the whole scenario.

Comment: @Leslie Norman: To me it still appears as a classpath resolution issue. Though, its hard to say why its happening. For a try you can also check by changing the order of included jars in `plugin.xml->Runtime->classpath`.

Comment: @Leslie Norman: Its nice to hear that the problem is gone :). I have updated my ans. Thanks.

Comment: @Favonius: You were right, it was classpath problem. Stil I don't know where was it coming from. Seeing your persistence I re-created my resources plugin from scratch. New plugin looks similar to old one, though, but my days long pain is gone. I appreciate your help.